# How to click svg tag with Selenium Webdriver and .Net core?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click on an "svg" tag to add an image to instagram, but I can't. There is a delay in the code and the action does not take place.
My project uses:

- Selenium webdriver
- Chromedriver
- .Net core 3.1

[image: Click Button]

```
            <div class="q02Nz _0TPg" data-testid="new-post-button" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">
                <svg aria-label="Nova publicação" class="_8-yf5 " fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
                    <path d="M31.8 48H16.2c-6.6 0-9.6-1.6-12.1-4C1.6 41.4 0 38.4 0 31.8V16.2C0 9.6 1.6 6.6 4 4.1 6.6 1.6 9.6 0 16.2 0h15.6c6.6 0 9.6 1.6 12.1 4C46.4 6.6 48 9.6 48 16.2v15.6c0 6.6-1.6 9.6-4 12.1-2.6 2.5-5.6 4.1-12.2 4.1zM16.2 3C10 3 7.8 4.6 6.1 6.2 4.6 7.8 3 10 3 16.2v15.6c0 6.2 1.6 8.4 3.2 10.1 1.6 1.6 3.8 3.1 10 3.1h15.6c6.2 0 8.4-1.6 10.1-3.2 1.6-1.6 3.1-3.8 3.1-10V16.2c0-6.2-1.6-8.4-3.2-10.1C40.2 4.6 38 3 31.8 3H16.2z">
                    </path>
                    <path d="M36.3 25.5H11.7c-.8 0-1.5-.7-1.5-1.5s.7-1.5 1.5-1.5h24.6c.8 0 1.5.7 1.5 1.5s-.7 1.5-1.5 1.5z">
                    </path>
                    <path d="M24 37.8c-.8 0-1.5-.7-1.5-1.5V11.7c0-.8.7-1.5 1.5-1.5s1.5.7 1.5 1.5v24.6c0 .8-.7 1.5-1.5 1.5z">
                    </path>
                </svg>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to click the `svg` element.
You should click the outer button:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@data-testid='new-post-button']")).Click();
```

Just to let you know. In case you will still want to click the `svg` element you can do it too with this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@data-testid='new-post-button']/*[name()='svg']")).Click();
```

Comment: If i use `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@data-testid='new-post-button']")).Click();` the exception occurs  : "The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:50039/session/c152f14670c2d538934e5b59523f59ae/element/63602091-da93-4a1a-bb8e-0cee5d54e072/click timed out after 60 seconds."  and if i use `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@data-testid='new-post-button']/*[name()='svg']")).Click();`  occurs  : "The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:50039/session/c152f14670c2d538934e5b59523f59ae/elements timed out after 60 seconds."

Comment: maybe iframe there? can you share a link to that page?

Comment: I put a larger snippet of code here  : https://jsfiddle.net/Mil1000/oe91fs3L/1/

Comment: As information for other users, to access this code in instagram it is necessary to click on f12 and then on f5.

Comment: Please, any comment?